# Does flash message (req.flash) exists in Sails 1.0.0 (beta)?

Tags: sails.js

I was trying Sails.js beta version (1.0.0-46) and noticed that flash messages are not available out-of-box:

```
req.flash(type, message)
```

I got a *TypeError: req.flash is not a function* message when trying to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ouch... just found the answer right in the upgrade docs ([Upgrading to v1.0](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0#?express-4)).

> The connect-flash middleware has been removed (so req.flash() will no longer be available by default). If you wish to continue using req.flash(), run npm install --save connect-flash in your app folder and add the middleware manually.

Run the command bellow:

```
npm install --save connect-flash
```

And modify the *config/http.js* file:

```
middleware: {
  flash    : require('connect-flash')(),

  order: [
    'cookieParser',
    'session',
    'flash', // <-- add this
    // 'bodyParser',
    'compress',
    'poweredBy',
    'router',
    'www',
    'favicon',
  ],
```

Comment: I havbe modified but its giving error not working...I am facing same problm in sails new 1.0 vesion.

Comment: Hi, the version I am using is 1.0.0-46.

Comment: Just facing the same problem, and here's how to solve it. You should add this in your `http.js` file:

```
    flash: (function _configureFlash() {
      var flash = require('connect-flash');
      return flash();
    })(),
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You now have access to `req.flash` via the [Sails Flash](https://docs.sailscasts.com/sails-flash/) hook in Sails 1.x and above

Answer (score -1):

Its in its session object `req.session.flash`, you can use it as

```
req.session.flash{type:'success', message:'your message'}
```

Comment: When using req.session.flash by itself you are just appending something to the session, after reading the value from req.session.flash, it will be still available to other requests. This is by no mean the desired behavior for flash messages.

Please refer to the connect-flash middleware documentation:

The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages. Messages are written to the flash and CLEARED AFTER BEING DISPLAYED to the user. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects, ensuring that the message is available to the next page that is to be rendered.